# Areas controller not returning partial view

Tags: dxa

I have created custom Area under my DXA project. I am trying to return a Partial View in the main view on click of hyperlinks. I have defined the Attribute routing to my `Areas` controller .

```
Areas Controllers
namespace ABC.Areas.AreaName.Controllers
{
    [RouteArea("areaName")]
    public class ControllerName : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("ControllerName/getcontent",Name = "areaName_Defaults")]
        public  ActionResult GetContent()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Areas/areaName/Views/Partial/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

My route is getting registered in the `Global.asax` but my controller action method is not getting hit on the click of hyperlink (in the main view which I am able to render from Tridion). I am using ajax call to do so. But everytime I am getting 404 not found and Item `/system/config/_all.json` not found for Localization '31'

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '@Url.RouteUrl("areaName_Defaults")',
  contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (d) {
    // alert(url);
    $("#SomeDiv").html(d);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm new to DXA myself, but this reminds me of an issue IO had in DD4T where you have ot make sure custom routes are BEFORE the main DD4T page route else your request will always be going through usual DD4T pipeline and generate a 404.

Comment: What is in your DXA log file (`site.log` by default)? Set log level to `DEBUG` (in `Log.config`) to get more diagnostic info.